# C++ Coin flip program error

Tags: c++, flip

I am trying to count consecutive heads in a coin toss.  Unfortunately, my counter for consecutive heads is not incrementing properly.  Any ideas?  Code and sample output below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "random.h"
using namespace std;

string FlipCoin (string flip);


int main() {
    string flip;
    int consecutiveHeads = 0;
    int totalFlips = 0;
    while (consecutiveHeads<3) {
        totalFlips++;
        if (FlipCoin(flip) == "heads") {
           consecutiveHeads++;
        } else {
            consecutiveHeads = 0;
        }
        cout <<totalFlips<<" "<< FlipCoin(flip) << " " << consecutiveHeads <<endl;
    }
    cout <<"It took "<< totalFlips <<" coin flips to get 3 consecutive heads."<< endl;
    return 0;
}


string FlipCoin(string flip) {
    if (randomChance(0.50)) {
        return "heads";
    } else {
        return "tails";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1 heads 1
2 tails 0
3 tails 1
4 heads 2
5 heads 3
It took 5 coin flips to get 3 consecutive heads.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `FlipCoin(flip)` generates a new random number. You call it twice, so it's generating two different random numbers. You should call `FlipCoin(flip)` once and store it in a variable.

```
...
string result = FlipCoin(flip);
if (result == "heads") {
    consecutiveHeads++;
} else
    consecutiveHeads = 0;
}
cout <<"It took "<< totalFlips <<" coin flips to get 3 consecutive heads."<< endl;
...
```

As somebody else mentioned, the `flip` variable in your `main` is uninitialized and unused. It's best to remove it. It was suggested that you pass `flip` as a reference in your `FlipCoin` function (using `&`). This most definitely has uses but it's not necessary. The simplest revision might be:

```
string FlipCoin() {
    if (randomChance(0.50)) {
        return "heads";
    } else {
        return "tails";
    }
}
```

**PS: If you remove the `flip` parameter from the function, you must also replace every occurence of `FlipCoin(flip);` with `FlipCoin();`**

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `FlipCoin` function you flip. Thus, you flip twice in each iteration of your `while` function. You may consider passing `flip` as reference to `FlipCoin`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "random.h"
using namespace std;

void FlipCoin (string &flip);


int main() {
    string flip;
    int consecutiveHeads = 0;
    int totalFlips = 0;
    while (consecutiveHeads<3) {
        totalFlips++;
        FlipCoin(flip);
        if (flip == "heads") {
           consecutiveHeads++;
        } else {
            consecutiveHeads = 0;
        }
        cout <<totalFlips<<" "<< flip << " " << consecutiveHeads <<endl;
    }
    cout <<"It took "<< totalFlips <<" coin flips to get 3 consecutive heads."<< endl;
    return 0;
}


void FlipCoin(string &flip) {
    if (randomChance(0.50)) {
        flip = "heads";
    } else {
        flip = "tails";
    }
}
```

Comment: @Barmar, yeah, `flip` may be pass as reference to `FlipCoin`

Comment: Your version of FlipCoin is unnecessary and confusing in regards to the original program. Not passing a flip value would be preferred.

Comment: My comment was based on your original answer that didn't redefine `FlipCoin` to take a reference.

Comment: Yup - that's the fix. Thanks!

Comment: @cpp, Passing `flip` as a reference is discouraged. If anything, the removal of the `flip` parameter from `main` and `FlipCoin` would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're calling `FlipCoin()` twice in each iteration: first to compare with `"heads"`, and then again to display what happened. You need to call it once, and put it in a variable:

```
while (consecutiveHeads<3) {
    totalFlips++;
    string curFlip = FlipCoin(flip);
    if (curFlip == "heads") {
       consecutiveHeads++;
    } else {
        consecutiveHeads = 0;
    }
    cout <<totalFlips<<" "<< curFlip << " " << consecutiveHeads <<endl;
}
```

P.S. What is the argument to `FlipCoin()` for?