# Coin Flip C++ Loop

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to make a coin flipper in c++. The point of it is to have the coin "flip" 100 times, and display the amount of times it was heads or tails.

For example: "The coin has been flipped 100 times. Heads = 68  Tails = 32

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

int main()

{
    using namespace std;

    random_device rd;

    default_random_engine random(rd());
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 2);

    int coin;
    int heads = 0;
    int tails = 0;

    coin = uniform_dist(random);

    cout << "I will flip this coin 100 times.";
    cout << "I will then print the results.";

    while (coin != 100)
```

How can I "flip" the coin 100 times and how would I go about making a loop for the coin?

Comment: Ask on code review stack exchange. Will get better answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ Coin flip program error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18566294/c-coin-flip-program-error)

Comment: @BrianTracy: No, do **not** ask on Code Review.  Code Review is only for working code, which this is not, and so it is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: Seems odd you'd figure out how to use c++11 random stuff and not know what a for loop is.

Comment: @perreal I don't think this is a duplicate of that one. That question is about an error in existing logic resulting in incorrect output. This one is asking how to start implementing that logic, not quite at the same stage. (Additionally, the goals of the programs are somewhat different.)

Comment: @Serlite, yes but it also contains many pointers to help the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a loop. What you want is a random number drawn from a binomial distribution:

```
std::binomial_distribution<int> distribution(100,0.5);
int heads = distribution(random);
int tails = 100 - heads;
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/binomial_distribution/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why a loop is hard for you but this should work.

```
for ( int count = 0; count != 100; ++count )
{
   int coin = uniform_dist(random);
   if ( coin == 1 )
   {
      ++heads;
   }
   else
   {
      ++tails;
   }
}
```